# Can't print the right result

Tags: c++

I wanted to get the program to calculate the cube of a number by using a pointer.
Here's my code, what is wrong with it? *the expected out put should be 5 and 125, while i get 5 and a random number*

```
using namespace std;

int cubeByreference(int *);
int main()
{

    int number = 5;
    cout<<"The original value of number is "<< number ;
    number = cubeByreference( &number);
    cout<<"\nThe new value of number is "<< number<<endl;

    return 0;
}

int cubeByreference(int *nPtr)
{
    *nPtr = *nPtr * *nPtr * *nPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the value from the function:

```
int cubeByreference(int *nPtr)
{
    *nPtr = *nPtr * *nPtr * *nPtr;
    return *nPtr;
}
```

Otherwise, you invoke undefined behavior. (`number` will have some undetermined value if you don't `return`, which could be the cause of the random output).

Note that this could just be a `void` function, since you are changing the argument. There's no need to "return" a value in 2 different ways.

Also, to avoid the pointers (and the associated syntax), you could take the argument by reference:

```
void cubeByValue(int &n)
{
    n = n * n * n;
}
```

Better still, change the function so that it accepts the argument by value. It makes the function easier to implement and use.

```
int cubeByValue(int n)
{
    return n * n * n;
}
```